# Django monthly payment app

Tags: mysql, django, python-2.7

I am trying to make a monthly payment application using Django. From the list of the subscribers, the admin selects the subscriber who is going to pay the monthly charge. From the subscriber detail page, the admin will continue with the payment.
I am using Mysql database. Currently there are two tables in the database.

First Table: For Subscribers (id, name, area, subscriberNumber, phoneNumber)
Second Table: For Monthly Payment (id, subscriberNumber, month, year, amount, discount, fine, billNumber)

What is the idea behind going through the payment system. What should I do to add the data that tells the admin that the Subscriber has payed the amount.